# Laravel 5.2 Auth::check() works after registration but not after logout and login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

First of all quite the beginner so this all is pretty new to me and I'm out of ideas so thought to ask some help.

I have database from old site which already had it's users table so I'm using the old database and integrating it with laravel. I created the needed extra fields to users table needed and ran:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Afterwards registration works great. User is created and Auth::check recognizes the user if I don't log out.

But if I log out and log back in with the user I just created, Auth::check doesn't recognize the user anymore.

I have touched nothing on config/auth.php and done no changes apart for the /User.php model to link it to old database.

Another strange thing I noticed is that artisan make:auth didn't seem to create any routes to routes.php, is this normal? Where does it gets the roots in this case?

What could possibly be the issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the route you access for the auth::check is inside `web` middleware. 
Your routes for register/login/resetpassword are in `Route::Auth();`

Your group should look like this:

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
      Route::auth();
      Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

      Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
      });

});
```

And if Route::auth() doesn't fix it for you, add them manually

```
        // Authentication Routes...
        $this->get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
        $this->post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
        $this->get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');

        // Registration Routes...
        $this->get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
        $this->post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');

        // Password Reset Routes...
        $this->get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
        $this->post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
        $this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@reset');
```

Comment: Thank you. For the answer. I actually have it exactly like you described. Didn't know that Route::auth() picks up the routes for those automatically though.I found the problem actually. From some reason the incremental ID of the user table has to be id even if I define it in the model. I had it ID (capital letters) and that caused the problem. I made it lowercase and poof, problem gone.